# Use only one OpenFileDialog for multiple and different situations

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I have a program that uses multiple `OpenFileDialog` but I want to use one. I have written a code that does that but is there a simpler way to do that?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _intFlag As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _intFlag = 1
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        _intFlag = 2
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        If _intFlag = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        ElseIf _intFlag = 2 Then
            TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not handling the `FileOk` event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

and similarly for the other `Button`.